# Why is Hidden and md:flex properties not working in my nextjs site

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

```
<div className="hidden flex-1 items-center justify-center space-x-6 md:flex">

        <a className="headerLink">Product</a>

        <a className="headerLink">Explore</a>

        <a className="headerLink">Support</a>

        <a className="headerLink">Business</a>
        
      </div>``
```

//tailwind file

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = {

content: [

```
'./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',

'./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
```

],

theme: {

```
extend: {

  fontFamily: {

    body: ['Montserrat', 'sans-serif'],

  },

},

screens: {

  sm: '480px',

  md: '768px',

  lg: '976px',

  xl: '1440px',

},
```

},

plugins: [],

}

The navigation ought to show on a large screen while it disappears on a small screen. for me to display the nav I have to change the hidden to flex, this would in turn display the navigation on the small screens also and I wouldn't want that

Comment: Your code seems to be working: [tailwind-playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/GSm2VHTgju). I would check if you installed tailwind-css correctly.

Comment: Please check if you have the `theme.screens` section inside `tailwind.config.js`. [Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens).

Comment: it's still not working. I added the theme.screens for most screen sizes in the config file, but it's to no avail... been having this issue on different projects and parts of the current one I am on..I am a noob to development but would definitely love to find a good resolve

Comment: Please share your `tailwind.config.js` file.

Comment: @stickyuser shared the config file as asked

Comment: Are the class names in the code as you have shared, or are they dynamically created? Also, I would suggest using the browser dev tools to see above the `md` breakpoint what styles are being applied and why `md:flex` isn't taking effect.

Answer (score 0):

I set 'important' to 'true' in the Tailwind configuration file, and now it works for me.

```
module.exports = {
important: true,
....
```

}